# Python: How to transform a tuple into a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, unicode, tuples

The following code fetches a tuple and prints it:

```
 query="SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE id_evento=1;"
 cur.execute(query)
 fetch=str(cur.fetchall()).decode('unicode-escape')
 print fetch
```

The printed tuple is the following:

```
[(1, u'Produção, u'Produção, u'NULL, u'NULL')]
```

I want to change that tuple to this:

```
 1,Produção,Produção,NULL,NULL
```

And then (or directly) to this, which is an array in which it's elements are the elements of that tuple, like:

```
list[1]= 1
list[2]= Produção
list[3]= Produção
list[4]= NULL
list[5]= NULL
```

This should be simple but I'm having such a hard time with it. 
Than you.

Comment: Does `L = list(fetch)` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't :/ Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: It looks like you might have a string of a list that has a tuple as the first element.  What does `type(fetch)` give you?

Comment: It says it's type tuples but I got around it by fetching from the database the elements one at a time and place them on a list and it worked. Not the ideal method but it works.

Comment: As you wish, but your not finding a good solution because your asking the question and supplying information so poorly.  Does it really say "it's type tuples"?  `tuples` isn't a type (though `tuple` is); and it doesn't make sense that `fetch` is a `tuple` because in the line before you've said `fetch=str(...`, so somewhere else you've changed either `fetch` or `str`.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
[(1, u'Produção', u'Produção', u'NULL', u'NULL')]
```

is a single-element list.  The only element in this list is a 5-tuple.

You can index the first element and convert it to a list like so:

```
elements = [(1, u'Produção', u'Produção', u'NULL', u'NULL')]
items = list(elements[0])
```

Comment: Doing `items=list(fetch[0])` and printing `fetch` returns `[u'[']`. Do you know why it's returning that and not `[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: l = [(1, u'Produo', u'Produo', 'NULL', 'NULL')]

In [10]: l1 = [iterl for iterl in l[0]]

In [11]: l1
Out[11]: [1, u'Produo', u'Produo', 'NULL', 'NULL']
```

Sorted, right?

Comment: No, `l1` returns `[u'[']` :/

Comment: Strange, my sample works fine, as you see in the ipython paste, are you using 3.x by any chance?

Comment: The thing is if I initiate `fetch= [(1, u'Produo', u'Produo', 'NULL', 'NULL')]` like this, it works fine. If I use the `fetch` tuple I got from the database it prints what I told you. So, I got around it and I'm fetching from the database the elements one at a time and place them on a list and it worked. Not the ideal method but it works.